# Lottie animation using @lottiefiles/react-lottie-player(v. 3.5.3) doesn't appear on iOS and iPadOS

Tags: reactjs, npm, animation, lottie

Does anyone using [@lottiefiles/react-lottie-player](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@lottiefiles/react-lottie-player) experiencing Lottie animation using @lottiefiles/react-lottie-player(v. 3.5.3) doesn't appear only on iOS and iPadOS devices? For Windows, Mac, Android web, it's all good.

For your information, I'm using React v. 16.14.0, not React Native.

I tried with the package version 2.2.2 first, then the latest version (3.5.3), and both results are the same.

[Code]

```javascript
import { Player } from '@lottiefiles/react-lottie-player';

...

            <Player
              ref={this.player}
              autoplay={false}
              loop={false}
              src={animationSource}
              style={{ width: '12rem' }}
            />
```

Thank you!